# How to search for a name in a struct/file

Tags: c++, string, file, search, struct

I have a struct that holds two names, but they are in character form- so an array
char[2][10]
it's supposed to be two names that are a maximum of ten characters long.
And I want to search through them.

```
    while (ans3==1)
{
    cout << "\nPlease enter the name you want to search"
        <<endl;
    cin >> searchName;
    for (int i=0; i < size; i++)
    {
        cout <<"\nsearching " <<endl;
        for (int k=0; k< 10; k++ )
        if ( MyData.name[i][k]==searchName[k])
        {
            cout << "\nName was found at position "<< k <<endl;
        }
        else 
            cout << "\nName not found at position " <<k <<endl;
    }

    cout << "\nDo you want to search for a name? (1 for y, 2 for n)" <<endl;
    cin >> ans3;
}
```

this compiles, but doesn't do what i want it to do. Can someone please assist. thanks.

Comment: `for (int k=0; k< 10; k++ )` will continue the search after the end of the string if the string is less than 9 characters. Consider using [`strncmp`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/string/byte/strncmp) instead.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

your current structure is assuming that the name starts at index 0 of the array. 
What I would recommend is check every char in the name array against the first char of the searched for name until you either hit the end of the name array or find a match. If you find a match then check the remaining chars in name array against the next char in the searched for string.
Because right now all you check for is if both strings start with the same letter.
To return the start pos of the name hold onto the index of the first match.
You can also use strcomp() if my suggestion was not at all what you were looking for.

Comment: thanks. The one that I wrote,  its kind of rudimentary but it gets the job done.

Comment: Made a for loop, running through the two names, checking the first letter and if first letter was found, it would run through the whole word. But only thing- when it runs thourgh- b/c if statement, it outputs: found at 1, found at 2 found at....